# MYSQL match keyword list Comma Delimited Text Field

Tags: php, mysql, csv, match, match-against

I have a list of keywords in a field called 'keywords' in a MYSQL database   For example the keywords field in the record contains 3 sample records

```
KEYWORD LIST 1: tree,apple,banana,cherry,flower,red apple,pink cherry,cat,mouse

KEYWORD LIST 2: cat,mouse,apple,red apple,flower,red appleberry

KEYWORD LIST 3: apple, red appleberry, flower
```

The keyword list is NOT an array - just a text field in a mysql database that has a lot of other fields.

When I run a MYSQL SELECT query from what I've seen 'so far' there are two ways: a) like %%   b) match against

Let's say I want to run a query against the word 'apple'

SELECT * where keywords like '%apple%' from table

This would bring up the records that contain the word 'apple' including the record above but it wouldn't necessarily give me any sequence of higher or lower. I'd have to do do the filtering of the results post query.

Supposing I was more detailed in my query, and chose 'red apple' it would still show a match, but I wouldn't necessarily get have KEYWORD LIST 1 be more relevant than 2 or 3.

Someone suggested using the Match Against instead

```
SELECT *, MATCH(Keywords) AGAINST('apple') AS Score
FROM table
WHERE Keywords like '%red apple%'
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

This is certainly heading in the right direction - however will it won't sort the results by an exact match being found as more relevant.  The relevancy would be based on how many repetitions of the word 'apple' appeared in the keyword list (this is the age old reason why all the search engines chose to ignore keywords altogether) - do you see where I'm going with this?

What I'm looking for is do process most of the logic in the MYSQL instead of reading it into an array and processing it in PHP as others have suggested. Hence this simplistic example.

Here's what the query ought to how it should be:

1) if my query is 'apple' Keyword list 1 should show up first

2) if my query is 'red apple' then Keyword list 2 should show up First because the word 'red apple' is CLOSER to the FRONT of the keyword list - closer to the beginning of the string.

BUT because of the LIKE %%

Keyword List 3 would show up even though the match was 'red appleberry' instead of 'red apple'

(It would be simplest if MySQL had some kind of 'explode' function that you could specify the comma (',') as the delimiter in the match but I don't know of any such method, do you? Of course you'd have to read the entire list of results into an array and then explode them in PHP.

3)  Suppose I search for 'red apple' and here's the bug: I'd still have a match on 'red appleberry' (record 3) - I don't want that. Record 2 should show up and then Record 1 and not even show record 3.

This is a discussion and an inquiry. Anyone have any suggestions?

My OWN ANSWER:
include the comma in the query
instead of searching for 'red apple' search for 'red apple,'
but what if the user put a space between - or if its at the tail end of the list of keywords?

QUESTION:
How can we search for specific SCORE in a comma delimited text field in MYSQL that uses the exact word (not a fragment) to come up with an ORDERED list of results.

Every attempt on this so far will still have Keyword List 3 show up higher than 2 even though red appleberry and red apple are two different phrases separated by commas.

Thanks! Let's discuss!

Comment: Stack is a Q&A site not a discussion one see [article](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions)

Comment: Why are the keywords all stuck in one column like that instead of another table?

Comment: Your database design is messed up. With this design you won't get a satisfying and performant way of what you want.

Comment: Good point. We are managing user input. People are putting their keywords into a form separated by commas. Everything in this project is about interpreting exsting human input results where people just put in a comma delimited field in a field called 'keywords.'

Comment: So why don't you split the user input ([explode()](http://php.net/explode)) before inserting it into the [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)(!!!) database and later when the user sees it again, you can join the single parts ([implode()](http://php.net/implode)). This would speeden up this query massively and would make it much more easy to implement.

Comment: How would you do that best? explode each keyword into its own table called 'keywords' and then assign the primary key to that? How would you then do a search by keyword and match it against the best results?  The project is about listing related websites that all share a common interest. Thanks! If you have a way to send me a private message please do so in my inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small project, you can do something like this

```
SELECT *, 
case when keyword like '%red apple%' then 1 else 0 end exact_match,    
MATCH(Keywords) AGAINST('apple') AS Score
FROM table
where keywords like '%apple%'    
ORDER BY exact_match DESC, score DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you.  Now for this particular search project we have 3 fields - they are very similar to what we're all familiar with:

TITLE - DESCRIPTION - KEYWORDS   - What I'm seeking to create is a statement that creates a 'score' based on the relevance of those 3 fields in a given search.  I realize that the way to do this would be to first create an INDEX - do you have any insights about how to create a FULL TEXT index that would quickly generate a score?

Comment: I think the idea of Full text index is that it scans your text and gives you the result at the order of relevance based on keywords. There is no score until you provide the search keyword.